# How do I get a build variable from xcodebuild?

Tags: xcode, makefile, xcodebuild

I am using the following command:

`xcodebuild -project eagle.xcodeproj -target eagle_test -showBuildSettings`

But I need to extract the `OBJROOT` as part of an external makefile. How would I get this?

Comment: Is this makefile run as a build phase of the target?

Comment: No, the target in the makefile is part of release process, so it builds, run tests, checks stuff, etc. I only want the target to run when I say so (not with every xcode compile)

Comment: Is this a makefile as in Unix `make`?

Answer (score 4):

Her you go. Parsed all nicely.

```
xcodebuild -project eagle.xcodeproj -target eagle_test -showBuildSettings | grep "OBJROOT" | sed 's/[ ]*OBJROOT = //'
```

Comment: I got it working with `OBJROOT = 'xcodebuild -project eagle.xcodeproj -target eagle_test -showBuildSettings | grep OBJROOT | cut -c15-'` (single quotes are ticks)

Comment: i updated mine to regex out the data you dont want. But yours works too.

Answer (score 0):

High level answer: As part of the makefile run the `xcodebuild -project eagle.xcodeproj -target eagle_test -showBuildSettings` command and parse the output for the value of `OBJROOT`.

Comment: It's hacky but I'm trying to do that with:
XCODE_BUILD_SETTINGS = `xcodebuild -project eagle.xcodeproj -target eagle_test -showBuildSettings | grep OBJROOT`
OBJROOT = `echo $${XCODE_BUILD_SETTINGS:14}`

But `echo $$OBJROOT` just prints `echo ${XCODE_BUILD_SETTINGS:14}` with ticks